# Can anyone check if this Palindrome c++ code is correct?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, function, palindrome

Here is a program i built to check palindrome words in c++. It does not work in usual way (to reverse the word and check if its same), but it directly checks each word from start and end;

madam, ada, hannah, racecar are the words i have tried and they seem to be correct.

```
    #include <iostream>

std::string is_palindrome(std::string text)
{
  int length=text.size();     //No. of characters
  int index=text.size()-1;    //No. of indexes
  int i;
  int x=0;                 //To store no of same character from both ends
  for(i=0;i<=index;i++)
  {
       if(text[i]==text[index-i])
     {x++;}
  }
  if(x==length)             //If all characters are same form opp ends
  {
    return "true";
  }
  else
  {
    return "false";
  }
}

int main() {

  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("happy") << "\n";

}
```

The results are correct, i just could not find a code like this, so just wanted to check it.

Comment: You might want to post this at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I think you should iterate not over all characters, but only over half of them, i.e. `for(int i = 0; i <= index / 2; i++)`. Instead of counting the equal characters you might exit (false) as soon as any pair is not equal.

Comment: Also, you could check if `if(text[i] != text[index-i]) return false;` and get rid of `x`.

Comment: i wouldnt return a `std::string` but rather a `bool`, it is much easier to convert a `bool` to `string` when needed than converting `"true"` / `"false"` to a `bool` in case you need it

Comment: @Mansoor had the same idea, but the return type is `string`

Comment: Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Answer (score 3):

Your function is too complicated. The parameter should be a constant referenced type, and the function should return a boolean value.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can look using a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome( const std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0, n = s.length();

    while ( i < n / 2 && s[i] == s[n - i - 1] ) ++i;

    return i == n / 2;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( "madam" ) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( "happy" ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
false
```

You could write the function shorter as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. However the function is less efficient than the function using a loop because it needs to allocate memory for the temporary string `std::string( std::rbegin( s ), std::rend( s ) )`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

bool is_palindrome( const std::string &s )
{
    return s == std::string( std::rbegin( s ), std::rend( s ) );
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( "madam" ) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( "happy" ) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above that is

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a palindrome is a string that is the same when reversed, you can use `std::equal` and a reverse iterator like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string &str)
{
    return std::equal(str.cbegin(), str.cbegin() + str.size()/2, str.crbegin());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_palindrome("poppy") << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

This approach avoids having to create a temporary string in reverse for the comparison.

Alternatively you can implement a loop with two indexes, one for the left and for the right, incrementing the left and decrementing the right:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string &str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    for (int left = 0, right = len-1; left < right; ++left, --right)
    {
        if (str[left] != str[right])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your logic is correct and will yield the right results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with people that this something for Code Review, but, your code looks correct. ... and why not throw in a few palindrome versions more? Here's one working with iterators so you can check ranges of any type with an equality operator:

```
template<typename It>
bool is_palindrome(It first, It last) {
    if(first == last) return true;
    It end = std::prev(last);
    while(first < end) {
        if(*first != *end) return false;
        std::advance(first, 1);
        std::advance(end, -1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And a one-liner:

```
bool is_palindrome = std::equal(str.begin(), 
                                std::next(str.begin(), str.size() / 2),
                                str.rbegin());
```